# LinqToSql как поменять псевдоним поля

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

Есть запрос на выборку данных, которые отправляются в dataGrid WPF:

```
var member1 = dataEntities.WorkExperience;
var query1 =
    from mem in member1
    where mem.Jobless_id == RegistrationData.JoblessId
    select new
    {
        mem.GroupPost.Label,
        mem.Post,
        mem.WorkPeriod.Label,
        mem.Dismissal_date
    };
dataGrid.ItemsSource = query1.ToList();
```

Вот код списка (колонки):

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Група посад" Binding="{Binding Path=Label}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Посада" Binding="{Binding Path=Post}"/>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Стаж роботи" Binding="{Binding Path=Work_period}"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата звільнення" Binding="{Binding Path=Dismissal_date}"/>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Конфликт происходит тут:

```
  mem.GroupPost.Label,
  mem.WorkPeriod.Label,
```

Типо 2 названия `Label` одинаковые...
Я хочу исправить это дело оператором `AS` (как в SQL): `mem.WorkPeriod.Label AS [Work_period]`. Но оно не хочет его принимать.
Можете подсказать, как его подогнать правильно плиз?

Comment: Ну так вы можете дать имена самостоятельно `select new
    {
        mem.GroupPost.Label,
        mem.Post,
        mem.WorkPeriod.Label,
        Dismissal_date = mem.Dismissal_date
    };`

Comment: ДА ДА ДА!!! это ОНО!!! спасибо БОЛЬШОЕ!!! затупил жестоко

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для задания новых имен необходимо проецировать в анонимный тип или описать свой класс. Первое значительно проще. Приведу пример:

```
...
select new { a.A, a.B }
```

или же явно задавать имена

```
...
select new { Field1 = a.A, Field2 = a.B }
```

оба варианта можно комбинировать

```
...
select new { a.A, Filed1 = a.A } // не будет конфликтов
```